# Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Drawing.Image' 

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "images/sample1.jpg?rnd=" + (new Random()).Next();  
    // added random for caching issue.
this.Controls.Add(img);
```

I get the error as

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Drawing.Image'   --->Line 1
>
> 'System.Drawing.Image' does not contain a definition for 'ImageUrl' and no extension method 'ImageUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Image' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  ---> Line2
>
> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.Control)' has some invalid arguments   ---> Line3
>
> Error    10    Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Web.UI.Control'

Please help me to solve the error.

Comment: Try to post question in normal Caps rather than All Caps.. looks like someone is shouting

Comment: @haris Sorry, i had my caps lock on and i noticed it after i had typed everything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the wrong Image class. Fully qualify it and it should work like you're expecting.

```
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    img.ImageUrl = "images/sample1.jpg?rnd=" + (new Random()).Next();  // added random for caching issue.
    this.Controls.Add(img);
```