# Add image from local system to listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, image, listbox, bitmapimage

I have a listbox and i want to update my listbox with all the logical drives. I want to show all the images in a parent and child format. I am using this code
  string[] path = System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives();

```
        foreach (string directories in path)
        {
            Bitmap bitimg = null;
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(directories);
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.jpg");
            for (int i = 0; i < Files.Count(); i++)
            {
                string fileName = Files[i].FullName;
                Uri uri = new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative);
                BitmapImage bitmap=new BitmapImage(uri);
                Image img = new Image();
                img.Source(bitmap);
                listBox1.Items.Add(img);
            }

         }
```

But i am getting error as

```
    Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Drawing.Image'
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976929/cannot-create-an-instance-of-the-abstract-class-or-interface-system-drawing-ima

Comment: @Andrew i am working on WindowsForms and System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image  is for WebForms.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing Wpf and Winforms, the BitmapImage Class is part of `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` which is part of WPF

Comment: @MarkHall if we can't use Image class in winforms then how can we add images in our listbox ?

Comment: A winforms listbox does not support Images, are you sure you are not wanting to use WPF? Aso to answer your question To create an Image you would use the Static Methods of the Image Class, something like Image.FromStream

Comment: @MarkHall i surely don't want to use WPF. It is not necessary to use ListBox. If there is any other control which will show all the directories and images in that directories in parent-child format, and also i can drop image from one control to another then i can use that. Please suggest some other control then..

Comment: @MarkHall basically i want to show the list of directories as we see in our windows explorer on right side control and whichever image we drag from this control and drop it on second control placed on left side, it should be dragged to left control. So suggest which controls should i use on right side and left side to do that ?

Comment: see if this CodeProject article helps.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14570/A-Windows-Explorer-in-a-user-control